# Set exchange mailbox size with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server

I have an app that shows select data about user accounts and allows password resets. I want to add the facility to set mailbox size. Is there any way to do this in VB.NET?

Comment: ...you haven't even googled this, have you?

Comment: That wasn't the helpful type of comment I was expecting on this site. I've spent several hours Googling and reading on this topic and found nothing helpful. If it is so obvious maybe you could take the time to post a link. I have found plenty of stuff on reading mailbox size and other articles that require you to either know the mailbox password or be running a script on the server but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Gladly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
Please: If you've done research and work and tried it, share it, show us your effort.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear.  The mailbox size is determined by how much mail it contains.  Are you asking how to change quotas?

Comment: Apologies, I'm using the wrong terminology as all our customers ask for an increase in their mailbox size, that's the wording I am using. I'm looking for a way to set quotas.

Comment: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/45496bdd-74c9-48ac-8b7b-5e3e9519f3bc

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.directory.management.mailbox.usedatabasequotadefaults%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx